# Is my calculation about this partial differentiation correct?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I want to calculate this equation
$\frac{\partial y^TB^{-1}y}{\partial y}$

according to the equation(81) of matixcookbook,

$\frac{\partial x^TBx}{\partial x} =(B+B^T)x$

B is a matrix calculated by y.

So,$\frac{\partial y^TB^{-1}y}{\partial y}$ becomes $\frac{\partial y^TB^{-1}y}{\partial y}=(B^{-1}+B^{-T})\cdot y + \frac{\partial B^{-1}}{\partial y}$
I am not sure if the second part,namely $+ \frac{\partial B^{-1}}{\partial y}$

can someone tell me if I am doing that correctly or not?

Comment: Does $B$ depend on $y$?

Comment: yes,B depends on y. So I added the second part,which is what I am not sure about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ depends on $x$ then, the derivative of $x^T A x$ w.r.t. $x_i$ (the $i$-th component of $x$) is

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x^T A x)  &=& \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\sum_{j,k}x_j A_{jk} x_k \\
&=& \sum_{j,k}\left(\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i}\right)A_{jk}x_k + \sum_{j,k}x_j\left(\frac{\partial A_{jk}}{\partial x_i}\right)x_k +
\sum_{j,k}x_jA_{jk}\left(\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial x_i}\right)\\
&=& \sum_{k}A_{ik}x_k + 
\sum_{j,k}x_j\left(\frac{\partial A_{jk}}{\partial x_i}\right)x_k + 
\sum_{j}x_j A_{ji}\\
&=& (A x)_i + (A^T x)_i + x^T \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x_i}\right)x
\end{eqnarray}

The derivative in the last term just means: take derivative of $A$ w.r.t. the $i$-th component of $x$. A more compact notation is

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^T A x) = (A + A^T) x + x^T \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right)x
$$

keeping in mind the meaning of the last term

Comment: so,for every element of $x$($x_{i}$), the derivative of $x^{T}Ax$ w.r.t $x_{i}$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}(x^T A x) = (A + A^T) x + x^T \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x_{i}}\right)x$, but for $x$, it is just $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^T A x) = (A + A^T) x $,without the second term right?@caverac

Comment: @SuiceMay No, for every element of $x$ $(x_i)$, the derivative of $x^T A x$ w.r.t $x_i$ is 

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x^T A x) = (A x)_i + (A^T x)_i + x^T \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x_i}\right)x
$$

The derivative w.r.t. $x$ is built by putting all these numbers together

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x^T A x) = (A + A^T) x + x^T \left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\right)x
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot,that was very helpful

Comment: @SuiceMay Happy to help